# Sybase Query Plan too large lots of "child tables"

Tags: jdbc, sap-ase, sql-execution-plan

I have a simple Query:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=1
```

This table is referred by at least 90 (X) other table :

```
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TABLEX_TABLE1
FOREIGN KEY (ID)
REFERENCES "db"."TABLE1"(ID)
```

Looking at the plan for the given query, it's really large.
We have `DIRECT RI FILTER Operator (VA = 103) has 98 children.` and then a bunch of `SCAN Operator (VA = X) FROM TABLE TABLEX ...`

The problem is that when we use batch deletion (JDBC) and reach immediately the procedure cache limit (which we did try to increase a lot, but the solution is not ok because children tables number is meant to increase).

However, my `DELETE` queries should only look into 5 tables for each different batch (I know that IDs XXX,YYY and ZZZ are referred by TABLEX, TABLEX+1, ... TABLEX+4). Is there a way to force the query plan to limit the scan to some tables ?

Modifying the data model is not really an option.

```
Sybase 15.0.3
JConnect3d 6.0.5
```

---

I did reduce the number of queries done in the batch and going from 1000 to 100 won't crash anymore. It's a solution but I would like to reduce the query plan, not the batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we ended up having a batch size computed from the number of child tables.

The more table the less update in the same batch.